# Gradle test not working: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:testReleaseUnitTest'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, circleci

I am new to android and circle ci. I am attempting to hook my android app up to circle CI. My app prints "hello world!" and that is all. I have not made any tests yet. Unfortunately I get an error indicating:

> !/bin/bash -eo pipefail
>   gradle test
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
>   Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:testReleaseUnitTest'.
>   SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/home/circleci/repo/local.properties'.
>
> Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
>   Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
>   See https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
>
> BUILD FAILED in 727ms
>
> Exited with code exit status 1

I am not sure what to do. I tried googling this error and couldn't find anything. Here is the public GitHub repo for my project:

https://github.com/Benjamin-Jenne/MapGame.git

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It turns out circle ci was running the tests on auto-generated branch "circle-ci-project setup". All I had to do was reset the branch to master by running an empty commit in command line.

git commit --allow-empty -m "set to master"

and then you git push